# Inline elements and line-height

Tags: html, css

I am confused about `line-height` in `inline` elements. I have been searching:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced
- http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/line-height
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

But I am not sure if I understand. I know that I can make the height exact if I convert to block with display:inline-block. But what I try to understand is how line-height inline elements work. Here are the questions:

- I have a text `font-size: 15px` but if I see the developer tools of the browser, it makes `18px`. Why? The `font-size` is just aproximate? or it does not measure the ups and downs?
- Why the background color of the `inline` element does not have the same `height` than the `line-height`? The `line-height` in `inline` elements measure the space of the line box, that is the space to the line above and below, but not the `inline` element itself. Is that the explanation?

[**Here an example to play with.**](http://jsfiddle.net/1b2rc1hr/)

**CSS:**

```css
#block-element {
  font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: grey;
}
#inline-element {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 15px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  margin: 0;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div id="block-element">
  <a id="inline-element" href="#">
    inline element font-size:15px but height:18px real
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that REC-CSS2 is an older revision that is now obsolete. The CSS2.1 spec is here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced

Comment: try using `em` instead of `px` and you might try putting a negative padding top/bottom in addition to tweaking the line height.

Comment: Can I add a reference ([Deep dive CSS: font metrics, line-height and vertical-align](https://iamvdo.me/en/blog/css-font-metrics-line-height-and-vertical-align)) I found for your question...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This might be confusing because in the inline formatting model there are different heights.

**Height of an inline box**

An element with `display: inline` generates an [inline box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-box):

> An *inline box* is one that is both inline-level and whose contents
>   participate in its containing inline formatting context. A
>   non-replaced element with a `display` value of `inline` generates an
>   inline box.

And [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height) determines the [height of that box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-box-height):

> The height of the inline box encloses all glyphs and their
>   half-leading on each side and is thus exactly 'line-height'

Therefore, your box is, in fact, `15px` tall.

**Height of a line box**

There are also [line boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting):

> In an inline formatting context, boxes are laid out horizontally, one
>   after the other, beginning at the top of a containing block.
>   Horizontal margins, borders, and padding are respected between these
>   boxes. The boxes may be aligned vertically in different ways: their
>   bottoms or tops may be aligned, or the baselines of text within them
>   may be aligned. The rectangular area that contains the boxes that form
>   a line is called a *line box*.
>
> The height of a line box is determined by the rules given in the
>   section on [line height calculations](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height).

In case a line box only contains non-replaced inline boxes with the same [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height) and [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align), those rules say that the height of the line box will be given by [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#line-height).

So in your case, this is also `15px`.

**Height of the content area of an inline box**

However, the developer tools of your browser said `18px`. That's because those `18px` are the height of the content area. It's also this content area (together with paddings) which is painted by the green background.

Note those `18px` might vary because [CSS 2.1 doesn't specify an algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced):

> The height of the content area should be based on the font, but this
>   specification does not specify how. A UA may, e.g., use the em-box or
>   the maximum ascender and descender of the font. (The latter would
>   ensure that glyphs with parts above or below the em-box still fall
>   within the content area, but leads to differently sized boxes for
>   different fonts; the former would ensure authors can control
>   background styling relative to the 'line-height', but leads to glyphs
>   painting outside their content area.)

If an UA implements the first suggestion, the content height will be given by [`font-size`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/fonts.html#font-size-props), which determines the em-box. This would what you expected, with the green box being `15px` tall.

However, most UAs don't seem to do that. That means that, probably, the height will be the height of the tallest glyph in the `font-family` and `font-size` used.

But using a `font-size` value of `15px` doesn't mean that the tallest glyph will be `15px` tall too. That depends on the font. This is somewhat analogous to `normal`, the initial value of [`line-height`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-line-height), which is defined as

> Tells user agents to set the used value to a "reasonable" value based
>   on the font of the element[...]. We recommend a used value for
>   'normal' between `1.0` to `1.2`.

That means that, if you use `font-size: 15px`, a "reasonable" `line-height` would be between `15px` and `18px`. In the "Verdana" font, Firefox thinks the best is `18px`; in the "sans-serif", it uses `17px`.

Comment: They seem to refer to the latest version superseeding the linked one: https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/refs.html#ref-CSS

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev CSS2.2 is a Working Draft, and CSS Snapshot says that CSS 2.1 still defines the core of CSS, only some parts are overridden by later specs.

Comment: Thanks for this helpful explanation.  In practice in a recent (2019) Chrome, I'm finding the exact ratio of line-height to font-size varies quite a bit between around 1.175 and 1.225, depending on overall document resolution or zoom level.  The factor is higher for small resolutions, and lower for large resolutions.    A situation where this is relevant is if you want to include an inline element with square dimensions (height == width), for example to display an SVG graphic which is centered on the text in line.

Answer (score -1):

```css
#block-element {
 font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
 font-size:15px; line-height:15px;
 text-decoration: none; color:black;
 margin:0;
 background-color:grey;
}


#inline-element {
 -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
 font-family: 'verdana', sans-serif;
 font-size:15px; line-height:55px;
 text-decoration: none; color:black;
 margin:0;
 background-color:green;
  
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div id="block-element">
 <a id="inline-element" href="#"> inline element font-size:15px but height:18px real </a>
</div>
```

**and line-height work on block element in you apply line-height 200px your element height  will 200px and your inner element mid on 200px height  **

inline element can't read height and padding top and bottom we need to read this properties we must apply any has layout properties like float , display: inline-block or block

only block elements are read line-height and padding properties 
in your code if you add float:left or disply:block css property add line-height and padding will be working

in your code in add only haslayout property you inline element working as a block element

Comment: `line-height` applies to all elements, including atomic inline ones.

Comment: Orial please explain your Question

Comment: It was a correction, not a question. You said that only block elements "read" `line-height`, but `line-height` applies to all elements.