# Text background with specific line-height not the same in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, webpage-rendering

I'm trying to get a semi-transparent background that "follows" the text: i.e. the background should not be a rectangular box, but rather a "jagged box" that stops at each linebreak.

Like this:

[image: Text background is a jagged bo]

I do this with the following style:

```
p {
  display: inline;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5); 

  font-family: "Montserrat";
  font-size: 18px;
  /* Add spacing between lines */
  line-height: 28px;
  /* Make sure background covers space between lines */
  padding-bottom: 6px;
}
```

An example can be seen here: http://jsbin.com/texala/6

The problem is that Firefox and Chrome renders these differently. The two browsers are using the exact same `.woff` font (not `.woff2`) and trying all different resets from [cssreset.com](http://www.cssreset.com/) still doesn't work.

## The problem

What you can see here is that the background from each line is overlapping in Firefox but not in Chrome.

[image: Chrome line-height + padding rendering]
[image: Firefox line-height + padding rendering]

I'm using OS X 10.7.5 with Firefox 35.0.1 and Chrome 40.0.22.14.111

I know that font rendering is different from platform to platform and browser to browser, but with an explicitly set line-height and font-size (and padding) in pixels -- isn't one of these two renderings wrong?

Furthermore - does anyone have a solution to this problem so that the background covers all the space between the lines with no overlap in both Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: Note to self: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363186/inline-elements-and-line-height

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with other line-height?:

```
p {line-height: 158%;}
```

Comment: Try to use something more standardized.

Answer (score -2):

Positioning of the CSS reset within the entire document structure is key. However, for this specifically,

```
p{display:inherit;text-align:justify};
```

### Edit

Read up on using EM and REM. It is superior to pixels in every way.

p{line-height:1.61em};

Comment: But this makes the background a rectangular box -- which is what I _dont_ want -- I want to keep the jagged lines, but avoid the background color overlap between lines

Comment: lol, my bad. I was reading this wrong because it was too long.