# Line height and background color (Span vs Div)

Tags: html, css

Its like few days pass and again when I try to recall what I read about `line-height` is something misleading what I am seeing

```
<span>Color me</span>

span {
    line-height: 52px;
    background: red;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Why it does not color complete box (i.e complete `line-height`)?

But When I do the same with `div` it colors as required.

```
<div>Color me</div>

div {
    line-height: 52px;
    background: red;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this particular case you need to add the following:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
  /* ... */
}
```

As for the reason **why**, see [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363186/inline-elements-and-line-height/28370374#28370374).

Comment: The why is not answered in the MDN link you posted.

Comment: @jdlm thanks for the fast update. But the question is not answered: why does the background-color not fill the whole line-height? Maybe there's an answer in the following link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28370374/603569

Comment: @Teetrinker Thank you, updated again. ;) I was focusing too much on `display: inline` vs `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 4):

Since span is an inline element it occupies only the height of the text and it does not cover the full area whereas in div it is a block element so it can cover the full area.

The method to convert the inline element to block element is

```
span{display: inline-block;}
```

Comment: ok, but how to keep the block "inline"? That is, i want the span to remain inline, instead of shifting down to a new line. Yet still fill the whole background without gaps between lines.

Comment: @johnywhy If you want to keep it inline, use `padding`. That will extend the height of the background color without extending the overall size. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56781081/1011956

Answer (score 2):

Because line-height doesn't work on inline element. span is an inline element. You may add display: block  or inline block to span's css

> On replaced inline elements such as buttons or other input element, line-height has no effect.

For more information, see [line-height@Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height)

Comment: 'line-height' does affect inline elements. You are referencing specifically "replaced" inline elements, which are a different thing than normal inline elements. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element

Answer (score 2):

The difference between span and div is that a span element is in-line and usually used for a small chunk of HTML inside a line (such as inside a paragraph) whereas a div (division) element is block-line (which is basically equivalent to having a line-break before and after it) and used to group larger chunks of code.

Answer (score 2):

The actual answer to this problem while keeping `span` elements as inline is to use the `padding` attribute.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/56781081/1011956