# Edit the height of the background-color of span / inline text

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to edit the height of the background color in my span?

**HTML**

```
<span class="highlight">Some highlighted text</span>
```

**CSS**

```
  .highlight{
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.5em;
        background-color: #4db6ac;
        line-height: 2em;
    }
```

What I want to do is for the highlight to be 1.8em. I'm not sure how to implement this without it being too tedious (ie. lots of divs ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a vertical linear-gradient with transparent top and bottom color (I've used red in the example).

The height of the element is `2em` because of the `line-height`, so `1.8em` is 90%. Create a gradient with two transparent strips (red in the demo) of height 5% each. The rest of the 90% will be the highlight color.

```css
.highlight {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 5%, #4db6ac 5%, #4db6ac 95%, red 95%);
  line-height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<span class="highlight">Some highlighted text</span>
```

Comment: Why do you assume that the height of the background (if I understood correctly) equals the line height?  [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/bwko7mqx/23/) it looks like the height is independent from the line height yet larger than the font size, but I don't know how the value is calculated?

Answer (score 8):

If anyone is looking for an answer as to how to expand the background color of a `<span>` elements text to be taller than the text itself, but still want the `<span>` to be inline, then none of these other solutions will work, since the background color is not affected by the `line-height` or `height` of a span. It's only affected by the `font-size` and `padding`. Here would be a proper solution for that case:

```css
body { 
    font-size: 1em; 
    line-height: 1.5em; 
}
span.highlight {
    background: yellow;
    padding: 0.25em 0; /* ('line-height' - 'font-size') / 2 */
}
span.no-padding { 
    padding: initial; 
}
```

```html
<p style="width:400px">
  Here is a bunch of text that will have some highlighted text within it.
  <span class="highlight">
    Here is some highlighted text that will span multiple lines and will have a full height background color.
  </span> 
</p>
<p style="width:400px">
  Here is also some highlight text without the padding. 
  <span class="highlight no-padding">
    Here is some highlighted text without a full height background, regardless of having the same 'line-height'
  </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you for the super helpful answer!  Not OP, but I'm a bit confused, the height of the span background without padding seems to not equal the font size (as I would've expected), see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/bwko7mqx/23/).  Also, changing the font family doesn't affect the height for me, so it seems to be in some way only dependent on the font size (in the case of padding 0), but what calculation is used here?

Answer (score 2):

By setting  display property to inline-block your background size will become equal to line height without adding any div. Hope this works for you!

```
 .highlight{
    display:inline-block;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background-color: #4db6ac;
    line-height: 2em;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add display property as inline-block, your background size will become equal to line height without adding any div. this will works for you!

```
.highlight{
display:inline-block;
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 1.5em;
background-color: #4db6ac;
line-height: 2em;
```

}