# How do I make the content box of an element fit the font-size of its contents

Tags: html, css, frontend, font-size

If you look at this codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwQrmm

```
`h2 {
  padding-top:16px;
  padding-bottom:16px;
  font-size: 16px;
}`
```

the h2 tag is set to have 16px in font-size but the height of its content box is 18px. Is there a way to set the height on the content box to match the font-size without manually setting its height with height: 16px. Also when the h2 tag becomes two lines, the content box should become 32px.

I tried searching this problem but couldn't find any answers. I'm sorry if this has been answered before.

Comment: What do you mean by 'content box'?

Comment: Is the inner most box that contains the text of an element. It appears as the blue box when you inspect in chrome dev tools. [More info here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set line-height to match font-size.

```
line-height: 16px;
```

When you write enough content (so there will be a second line), it'll become 32px.

However this isn't suggested. The content will become too crowded, the text will be too close to the text above (and below).
Line-height should be between 1,2x-1,5x of text-size.

Comment: The content area of a div may be higher then the line-height though, see https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inline-non-replaced or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363186/inline-elements-and-line-height