# Why don't containers expand to fit their inline elements

Tags: html, css

I simply have a container like a `div` or a `button` which contains an **inline** element with **padding** - the container doesn't grow to fit the inline element.

```css
button, div {
  background: blue;
}

span {
  background: orange;
  /*display: inline-block; */ /* toggle to see container element grow */
  padding: 4em;
}

hr {
  margin:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="btn__content">
        I'm div inline content
    </span>
</div>

<hr>

<button class="btn" type="button">
    <span>
        I'm button inline content
    </span>
</button>
```

**Why does this happen?**

**NB:** I'm not looking for a **fix** - (for instance, I already know that I could `display:flex` on the container and that would make the container expand to the content)

Rather, I'm looking for an explanation from a credible source like the spec which explains this behavior of inline elements.

Comment: @j08691 - 1) how on earth did find that question - I searched for an answer online before I posted and didn't find that post 2) the answer over there is a bit lacking and doesn't really give an authoritative explanation 3) It  is lacking  a source and I asked for a sourced answer

Comment: I use Google to search SO rather than SO's search since it kinda sucks. And the answer is partly given in the dupe I closed this for, but the actual reason has to do with the [box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model). "note that, for non-replaced inline elements, the amount of space taken up (the contribution to the height of the line) is determined by the line-height property, even though the border and padding appear visually around the content."

Comment: @j08691 I would appreciate it if you could post an answer here - with a link to the spec explaining this. I really tried to read the spec and came across a similar explanation - but I didn't understand. (What does line height have to do with this?) I was looking for a thorough answer. Please reopen and either answer or let someone post a thorough answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is explained in the [Visual Formatting model documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting) (emphasis mine):

> In an inline formatting context, boxes are laid out horizontally, one
>   after the other, beginning at the top of a containing block.
>   Horizontal margins, borders, and padding are respected between these
>   boxes. The boxes may be aligned vertically in different ways: their
>   bottoms or tops may be aligned, or the baselines of text within them
>   may be aligned. The rectangular area that contains the boxes that form
>   a line is called a line box.
>
> The width of a line box is determined by a containing block and the
>   presence of floats. **The height of a line box is determined by the
>   rules given in the section on line height calculations**.

The [line height](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height) is then calculated as:

> The height of a line box is determined as follows:
>
> 1. The height of each inline-level box in the line box is calculated. For
>      replaced elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements,
>      this is the height of their margin box; for inline boxes, this is
>      their 'line-height'. (See ["Calculating heights and margins"](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins) and the
>      [height of inline boxes](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#inline-box-height) in ["Leading and half-leading"](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#leading).)
> 2. The
>      inline-level boxes are aligned vertically according to their
>      'vertical-align' property. In case they are aligned 'top' or 'bottom',
>      they must be aligned so as to minimize the line box height. If such
>      boxes are tall enough, there are multiple solutions and CSS 2.1 does
>      not define the position of the line box's baseline.
> 3. The line box height is the distance between
>      the uppermost box top and the lowermost box bottom.  Empty inline elements
>      generate empty inline boxes, but these boxes still have margins,
>      padding, borders and a line height, and thus influence these
>      calculations just like elements with content.

And as [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Introduction_to_the_CSS_box_model) notes about the box model:

> Note that, for non-replaced inline elements, the amount of space taken
>   up (the contribution to the height of the line) is determined by the
>   line-height property, even though the border and padding appear
>   visually around the content.

and reiterated by the [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/visudet.html#q15) for inline non-replaced elements:

> The 'height' property doesn't apply, but the height of the box is
>   given by the 'line-height' property.

https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/visudet.html#q15

Where the line height is "the height that is used to calculate line box height." So while padding or borders might give the look of height to an inline element, only the line-height property will affect parent nodes. As you can see in the example below, the line height on the spans is affecting the height of the parent div.

```css
button,
div {
  background: blue;
}

span {
  background: orange;
  line-height: 10em;
}

hr {
  margin: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="btn__content">
        I'm div inline content
    </span>
</div>

<hr>

<button class="btn" type="button">
    <span>
        I'm button inline content
    </span>
</button>
```

See also [Inline elements and line-height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363186/inline-elements-and-line-height)

Comment: Would you know by any chance the reasoning behind this? I know understand what the spec is saying but what's the logic behind this?

Comment: You want the logic behind why inline elements don't have a real height and instead sort of have a height as defined by their line-height property?

Comment: Yes please :) Sorry for the additional question... But I still feel like I'm missing something

Comment: I don't know if anyone other than those involved with writing the actual spec could comment on that. You have two main types of elements, inline and block, and they have different properties because they need to behave differently. Why the line-height was chosen or allowed to influence the height of an inline element is beyond my pay grade I'm afraid.

Comment: Fair enough, I guess that's a question for the guys at w3c

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's because of these two sections:

- [9.4.2 Inline formatting contexts](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-formatting)

  > The height of a line box is determined by the rules given in the section on line height calculations.
- [10.8 Line height calculations: the 'line-height' and 'vertical-align' properties](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height)

  > The height of each inline-level box in the line box is calculated. For replaced elements, inline-block elements, and inline-table elements, this is the height of their margin box; for inline boxes, this is their 'line-height'.

Setting a line-height does change the height of the containing box

```css
button, div {
  background: blue;
}

span {
  background: orange;
  /*display: inline-block; */ /* toggle to see container element grow */
  padding: 4em;
  line-height: 8em;
}

hr {
  margin:100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <span class="btn__content">
        I'm div inline content
    </span>
</div>

<hr>

<button class="btn" type="button">
    <span>
        I'm button inline content
    </span>
</button>
```