# How to align blocks inside text verticaly

Tags: html, css, flexbox, vertical-alignment

How to vertically align center `.sub-block-2` element (like `.sub-block-1`) ?
.sub-block-1 should be display=flex
.sub-block-2 should be display=inline-flex
Behavior should be the same as now except .sub-block-1 and .sub-block-2 should be vertically centered

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class='holder'>
  Some text
    <div class="block">
      <div class="sub-block-1"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div class="sub-block-2"></div>
    </div>
    dsdfsd sdfsdf dsfsdfsdf sdfsdfsdf sdfsdf sdfsdf
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 300px;
}

.holder {
  line-height: 30px;
}

.block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sub-block-1 {
  display: flex;
  background: #000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 60px;
}

.sub-block-2 {
  display: inline-flex;
  background: #000;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

codepen https://codepen.io/ruvi/pen/yLaryJq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`inline` elements are a little funky with line height. ([thread on how line-height affects inline elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28363186/inline-elements-and-line-height))

Adding `line-height: 0;` to `.block` will align both `sub-block1` and `sub-block2` vertically, although if there's any text inside `.block`, there will be no extra space between lines.

```
.block {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  overflow: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
}
```